# Linux, Grep to math string without character

Tags: regex, linux, grep

Im trying to install [LOG4PLSQL](http://log4plsql.sourceforge.net/).
There is a build process on linux server, which put logs into file.

After processing all files there is a command, which checks text file if it contains a *ORA-* string,

Problem is, that in log4plsql code actually contains one *ORA-*:

```
BEGIN
build   20-Jun-2018 09:22:28    1960       checkAndInitCTX(pCTX);
build   20-Jun-2018 09:22:28    1961       LLTEXT :=   'SQLCODE:'||SQLCODE ||' SQLERRM:'||SQLERRM || CHR(10) ||
build   20-Jun-2018 09:22:28    1962            'Error back trace:' || CHR(10) ||
build   20-Jun-2018 09:22:28    1963             replace(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace, 'ORA-06512: ', ''); -- <<<<<<<<<<
build   20-Jun-2018 09:22:28    1964       log(pLEVEL => PLOGPARAM.DEFAULT_FT_ERR_BTRACE_LEVEL, pCTX => pCTX,  pTEXT => LLTEXT );
build   20-Jun-2018 09:22:28    1965  END full_error_backtrace;
build   20-Jun-2018 09:22:28    1966  
build   20-Jun-2018 09:22:28    1967  
build   20-Jun-2018 09:22:28    1968  FUNCTION getLOG4PLSQVersion
build   20-Jun-2018 09:22:28    1969  RETURN VARCHAR2
```

and although build has no errors, this grep function find one in package code and treat it like an error.

Grep responsible for finding ORA: `grep "ORA-"`
I modify it to: `grep "[^']ORA-"`

and ORA- with ' ('ORA-) is now invisible, but invisible is also actual error:

```
ORA-00955: name is already being used by existing object
```

so for example, in this log:

```
BEGIN
       checkAndInitCTX(pCTX);
       LLTEXT :=   'SQLCODE:'||SQLCODE ||' SQLERRM:'||SQLERRM || CHR(10) ||
            'Error back trace:' || CHR(10) ||
             replace(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace, 'ORA-06512: ', '');
       log(pLEVEL => PLOGPARAM.DEFAULT_FT_ERR_BTRACE_LEVEL, pCTX => pCTX,  pTEXT => LLTEXT );
END full_error_backtrace;
ORA-00955: name is already being used by existing object
```

my grep wont find any ORA.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: If I have read this correctly then assuming all of the errors have a line beginning with 'ORA' we can `grep "^ORA-"`? The `^` matches the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you add the `[^']` to the regex `grep` expects a character on the left-hand side of `ORA-`, but - since the pattern is potentially at the beginning of the line in the case of a genuine error - it will potentially fail to find one (as it has done in your example above).

Some regex guru might have a more elegant solution, but the following works for me:

```
grep -E "(^|[^'])ORA-" output.log
```

That will match lines which either *begin* with `ORA-` *or* contain the pattern `ORA-` preceded by *any character except `'`*.

My `grep` version:

```
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.27
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use -P for perl-compatible regexps

grep  -P "^ORA-|\'ORA" log